# RequireJS, AngularJS and init() called twice

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

Have a RequireJS and AngularJS app misbehaving with the controller being called twice destroying data for a specific detail. Tried removing the init() in the controller but then the data does not load until a refresh is performed. Any assistance would be helpful. Code is as follows:

Index.html file

```
<head>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-main="main.js" src="../Scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-cloak>
        <div data-ng-view ></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js file

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        // define alias for the directories
        'mod': '_modules'
    }
});
require([
    // these are the java script files without the .js at the end
    // that I want to be global accessable
    "mod/appMod"
    ,"/App/NorthernStars/Ctrl/northCtrl.js"
],
    function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['g2vStars']);  // kick off AngularJS and the name of the app
    }
);
```

appMod.js

```
var dependencies = ['mod/northMod'];
define(dependencies, function () {
    'use strict';
    var g2vStar = angular.module("g2vStars", ['northStars']);
    return g2vStar;
});
```

northMod.js

```
var dependencies = ['../../Scripts/angular-route.js']
define( dependencies,
    function () {
        'use strict';
        var northStars = angular.module('northStars', ['ngRoute']);
        northStars.config(['$routeProvider',
            function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    controller: 'nsCtrl',
                    templateUrl: '/App/NorthernStars/Views/northStarView.html'
                })
                .when('/northList', {
                    controller: 'nsCtrl',
                    templateUrl: '/App/NorthernStars/Views/northStarView.html'
                })
                .when('/searchNorth', {
                    controller: 'nssCtrl',
                    templateUrl: '/App/NorthernSearch/Views/northSearchView.html'
                })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
            }
        ]);
        return northStars;
    });
```

northCtrl.js

```
var dependencies = ['../../_modules/northMod.js','../Services/northFactory.js'];
define(dependencies, function (g2v, factory) {
        'use strict';
        var nsCtrl = function ($scope, nsFactory) {
            $scope.headerMessage = "List of Northern Stars classified as G2V Stars. ";
            $scope.dataObjects = [];
            $scope.dataDetail = {};
            $scope.crap = true;
//Called from the northStarView.html`enter code here`
            $scope.getDetail = function (index) {
                var id = $scope.dataObjects[index].g2v_ID;
                $scope.dataDetail = nsFactory.getObject(index);
                $scope.crap = false;
//After this the entire controller runs again
            };

            function init() {
                    $scope.dataObjects = nsFactory.getObjects();
            };
//If I dont have this the data is not loaded until a refresh  
            init();
        };
        g2v.controller("nsCtrl", ['$scope', 'nsFactory', nsCtrl]);
    });
```

northFactory.js

```
var dependencies = ["../../_modules/appMod.js"];

define(dependencies, function (g2v) {
    'use strict';

    var nsFactory = function () {
        var factory = {};
        var dataItems = [];
        var data = [{ "g2v_ID": "c516634e-e8a1-4872-bbd3-deacf6387770", "HIP": 36921, "SAO": 33726, "RA": "12:10", "DEC": "20:46", "Magitude": 5, "StarType": "Yellow", "SearchFor": 16 }, 
                    { "g2v_ID": "7488d47b-c102-4984-bc9f-6c5a68b72c8b", "HIP": 39193, "SAO": 17224, "RA": "14:12", "DEC": "8:08", "Magitude": 13, "StarType": "Fuscia", "SearchFor": 19 },
                    { "g2v_ID": "7dae1f2f-d3dc-42d6-a69a-9b18333d556f", "HIP": 47480, "SAO": 38030, "RA": "20:05", "DEC": "20:37", "Magitude": 7, "StarType": "Indigo", "SearchFor": 17 },
                    { "g2v_ID": "08f4bd26-ef7f-44d9-ac1b-c60df3bfb724", "HIP": 12119, "SAO": 31825, "RA": "16:10", "DEC": "21:05", "Magitude": 6, "StarType": "Teal", "SearchFor": 8 }
        ];
        factory.getObjects = function () {
            return data;
        };

        factory.getObject = function (id) {
            return data[id];
        };
        return factory;
    };
    g2v.factory("nsFactory", [nsFactory]);
});
```

northStarView.html

```
<div style="top: 1px; height: 50px; background-color: #FBFBEF; border: #F2F5A9 groove; ">
    {{headerMessage}}
</div>
<div style="margin-left:5px; overflow-y:auto; height:95%;">
    <table class="padded-table alter-row" border="1" style="background-color: #A4A4A4; border: #f2f5a9 groove; ">
        <thead class=" control-label">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:100px; text-align: center; display:none;">ID</td>
                <td style="width:100px; text-align: center;">HIP</td>
                <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">SAO</td>
                <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">RA</td>
                <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">DEC</td>
                <td>Magitude</td>
                <td>Star Type</td>
                <td>Option</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="dataItem in dataObjects">
                <td style="display:none">{{dataItem.g2v_ID}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:right; padding-right: 5px;">{{dataItem.HIP}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:right; padding-right: 5px;">{{dataItem.SAO}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:right; padding-right: 5px;">{{dataItem.RA}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:right; padding-right: 5px;">{{dataItem.DEC}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:right; padding-right: 5px;">{{dataItem.Magitude}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:right; padding-right: 5px;">{{dataItem.StarType}}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" data-ng-click="getDetail($index)">Details</a></td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="padded-table alter-row" border="1" style="background-color: #A4A4A4; border: #f2f5a9 groove; ">
        <thead class=" control-label">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:100px; text-align: center; display:none;">ID</td>
                <td style="width:100px; text-align: center;">HIP</td>
                <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">SAO</td>
                <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">RA</td>
                <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">DEC</td>
                <td>Magitude</td>
                <td>Star Type</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none">{{dataItem.g2v_ID}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:right; padding-right: 5px;">{{dataDetail.HIP}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:right; padding-right: 5px;">{{dataDetail.SAO}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:right; padding-right: 5px;">{{dataDetail.RA}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:right; padding-right: 5px;">{{dataDetail.DEC}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:right; padding-right: 5px;">{{dataDetail.Magitude}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:right; padding-right: 5px;">{{dataDetail.StarType}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Problem is when the data-ng-click="getDetail($index)" is clicked and the $scope.getDetail in the controller run then the entire controller reinitializes itself and I lose my detail info.

What Have I done incorrectly??

Ken

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only this:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['g2vStars']);
```

Use this:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['g2vStars']);
});
```

You´ve to wait(document to be ready...) to bootstrap your angular application.

Comment: Thanks for you input. Tried your suggestion within the main.js      angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['g2vStars']); 
    }
)); but no love was produced only an error

Comment: from where is coming "angular" here in your app: function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['g2vStars']);  
    }

Comment: AngularJS is being loaded in the index.html page prior to the RequireJS file being loaded. But I think I've figured out the problem -- I was using an anchor tag instead of a button; now it no longer reloads the controller. Again thanks for you input Rodrigo.

Comment: you're doing it wrong, the best practice is to require angular with requireJs.